# Change today's date and time in php

Tags: php, datetime

Is it possible to change php's current date and time (something like set_time(strtotime('1999-09-09')) so when i call time() it will return me timestamp for 1999-09-09? I need to set it globally for whole app.

**EDIT**

I already have one old app and i need to make possible to set up current date. 
I can't accept any custom functions. Imagine i should review all the code and replace every time() call. Even if i'll do so then it will not help because there are functions like getdate() which i need to replace as well.

Comment: Sometimes making massive updates to entire projects is a necessity. That's why they invented revision control systems. It's also possible to create a script which searches through every file for a the text "time()" and replaces it with "myTime()". This is fairly simple using `file_get_contents()`, `str_replace()`, and `file_put_contents()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `time()` functions actually asks the system clock for the time, so you'd have to update the time of the server's system clock. A few things to keep in mind:

- This is done differently on a Unix server than a Windows server. If you want code compatible with both, you have to be careful
- Sometimes (especially in shared hosting situations) you aren't allowed to change the system time
- Changes to system time will remain after the script has executed unless you change it back later. Therefore you risk really screwing up the system clock.

If you want to change the time globally for an entire app, I recommend having a static variable `$timeOffset` and create your own `time()` function as follows:

```
function myTime(){
    global $timeOffset;
    return time()+$timeOffset;
}
```

If you've taken all of that into account and still want to change the system time, however, you would need to send a command to the shell using `shell_exec()`

In Windows, the code would look like this:

```
shell_exec("date 09-09-99"); // Use "date mm-dd-yy" or "time hh:mm:ss", respectively
```

In UNIX, according to the `date` man page, the code would look like:

```
shell_exec("date 0909hhmm1999"); // It says "date MMDDhhmiYYYY". I'm not sure how to set seconds, although I assume "mi" = "minutes"
```

Comment: You risk screwing up the system clock anyway. Example: you run the script at 11:59:55, set clock two hours back, finish, set it two hours forward, it now says 12:00:10. Unfortunately, you had a process scheduled to launch at 12:00:00 - will it launch? The answer is "nobody knows" - according to the clock, 12:00:00 never happened. (you need pretty high permissions to mess with the clock anyway, and if you're running the server as root, you're already in twenty kinds of trouble)

Comment: as i understand i need proper rights to change date thru shell. Not sure that it is possible for www-data or apache2 user. Anyway good point. Will check it out.

Answer (score 20):

You could also check the [Timecop PHP module](https://github.com/hnw/php-timecop), worked perfectly in my case.

After installing it, you can travel back & forth in time with just one line of code.

Comment: No longer maintained, but see fork at https://github.com/kiddivouchers/php-timecop, or refer to my answer for another option under Linux.

Answer (score 5):

PHP doesn't have a date and time on its own. time() returns the current timestamp of the server's time. Depending on your operating system, it may well be that you (i.e. the user that runs your script's process) are actually not allowed to change the server date and time.

Which asks a different question: Why do you want to do this?

Better would be to implement your own time() function:

```
class myTime
{

    private static $offset = 0;

    public static function getTime()
    {
        return time() + self::$offset;
    }

    public static function setTime($time)
    {
        self::$offset = $time - time();
    }
}
```

And then, everywhere where you use `time()`, use `myTime::getTime();`. To set the time, use `myTime::setTime($time)` where `$time` is the timestamp you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. PHP gets its time from the system time. The only way you can change what PHP sees as the time is to change the system time.

It *may* be feasible for you to do that using `exec()` or something similar, but probably not advisable.

A better solution may be to create your own time function, which you can specify, using an offset.

eg:

```
function mytime() {
    return time()+set_mytime();
}

function set_mytime($new_time=null) {
    static $offset;
    if(!$new_time) {return $offset;}
    //$new_time should be a unix timestamp as generated by time(), mktime() or strtotime(), etc
    $real_time=time();
    $offset=$real_time-$new_time;
}

//usage:
set_mytime(strtotime("1999-09-09");
$faketime=mytime();
.... do something that takes a bit of time ....
$faketime2=mytime();
```

That's just something I've thrown together quickly for you. I haven't tested it, so there may be (probably are) bugs, but I hope it gives you enough to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your PHP script from a command-line on Linux, the `faketime` utility can be used to change the system time seen by PHP (or any program).  It also lets you change the rate at which time advances.

Note that times obtained from external services, such as via database queries (i.e. `SELECT NOW()`) will continue to show system time, unless they have also been launched with `faketime`.

Thanks to @zmf for the link to [hnw/php-timecop](https://github.com/hnw/php-timecop) (no longer maintained), which led me to the active fork [kiddivouchers/php-timecop](https://github.com/kiddivouchers/php-timecop), where `faketime` was mentioned in the latest commit.

Answer (score -1):

You may also try to use global `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` variable (available since PHP 5.1.0) and replace it on run-time.