# PHP - Setting up/emulating fake date

Tags: php, date

I have a bit weird question. Is it possible to set up fake date in PHP for the time in which script is working? I am using API which uses time periods, for example when you send request to get some data, you can specify time period (for example one month, but these periods are fixed) and it will return results from request_time-1month to request_time. Obviously, request data is present time, so I want to emulate this present time (for example set date from 10 May to 15 April). Is it possible? I can't see anything helpful in PHP documention and I don't even know if it would work, because I'm not sure if this API uses time from server in which it works or independent server which stores aforementioned data. But maybe someone has any idea.

Thanks from advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API you are connecting to is using "request_time - 1 month", then what *your* script thinks the time is isn't relevant, only what time *the script behind the API* thinks it is. (As a silly analogy: if a shop closes at 5PM, setting your watch early won't let you in at 5:30; you'd need to sneak in and change the clock on the wall so that the staff don't lock up.)

So unless you can find a way to fool the remote API into thinking you sent the request at a different time, there is nothing you can do.

If you control the API, then just edit the API to have a parameter which over-rides the definition of "now", perhaps only allowed in a special debug mode.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Unfortunately, I am unable to do anything, because I can't control the API. Well, I need to find another way. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 15):

Use libfaketime (https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime). On ubuntu - just install faketime using apt-get or aptitude.

1. If you want to fake time for console app:

   ```
    LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="2008-01-01 00:00:00" php yourscript.php
   ```
2. If you want to fake apache time, you will need to start apache with libfaketime preloaded. Just put

   ```
    export FAKETIME="2008-01-01 00:00:00"
    export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1
   ```

into `/etc/apache2/envvars` and restart Apache. Now your server response will always look like

```
$ curl -D - http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT
ETag: W/"420419-b1-4429c2a6653ac"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 177
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

**2019 UPDATE :**

On the latest systems, you would need a 64-bit version of libfaketime so you'd need `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/faketime/libfaketime.so.1` (thanks @jtrautmann), or even `libfaketimeMT.so.1` in a multithreaded environment.

Also, there are three ways to specify the faked time:

- By setting the environment variable `FAKETIME`
- By using the file given in the environment variable `FAKETIME_TIMESTAMP_FILE`
- By using the file `.faketimerc` in your home directory
- By using the file `/etc/faketimerc` for a system-wide default

Also, it is perfectly valid to use libfaketime inside a docker container.

Comment: I could successfully adapt this on Arch+lighttpd+FastCGI: Install `libfaketime` from community, then edit `/etc/lighttpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf` (or where appropriate), and add `"FAKETIME" => "@2008…", "LD_PRELOAD" => "/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1"` to `bin_environment`. (Maybe check `pacman -Qll libfaketime` first).

Comment: This isn't working for me. I had to set `LD_PRELOAD` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/faketime/libfaketime.so.1`. When executing `curl -D - http://localhost`, I get an answer with the fake time, but when I open a page in the browser, the date hasn't changed. Do you maybe have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @jtrautmann - it depends how do you check the date in the browser. If you see proper Date header in the response with curl - you should see the same Date header when using browser. If you are accessing date functions with PHP - you should also get fake date. However, if you are accessing date from javascript within the browser - you will get actual date, not the fake one

Comment: @AleksandrGuidrevitch The date header in the browser is indeed the fake date. But through the `date` function from PHP I get the current date of my machine and not the fake date. That javascript wouldn't work with it makes sense, but that isn't my problem.

Comment: @jtrautmann, If PHP is run as mod_php in apache and apache reports fake date in Date header, then PHP date() function should also return fake date, as it inherits libraries and environment from the parent process, I just double checked that to be 100% sure. My only guess is that your PHP interpreter is not part of the webserver - eg it is running in a different process (eg as a standalone FPM/CGI server). In this case you should start this server with preloaded and configured libfaketime as well

Comment: @AleksandrGuidrevitch You're right, thanks for the hint! It's true I'm using FPM. But I haven't discovered how to configure FPM to use `libfaketime`. I opened a question here, maybe you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458394/fpm-setting-up-libfaketime

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```sh
apt-get install faketime
faketime '2021-04-26 08:15:42' php cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the date and time you access through PHP is the server's system time. So if you are able to change that, you can achieve what you need. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923946/977431

Although personally, i would recommend just using a function which returns -30 days (for example) from the current date. When you would like to change the date back, replace the function with the real `getdate()`.

Comment: I used shell_exec and yes, date() returns 'my' date, but results returned by API are still the same. Seems like I have nothing to say in matter of time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you're testing something, you shouldn't rely on system configuration at all - better to do something like:

```
my_function(\DateTime $now = null) {

  if($now === null) {
      return new \DateTime();
  } else {
      return $now;
  }

}
```

In your normal code, you just call `my_function()`, but in your test, you call

```
$now = \DateTime::createFromFormat(...);
my_function($now);
```

Similar idea if it's for production code. Pass the date in as a parameter, instead of leaving the function to get it.

```
my_function(\DateTime $datetime) {
  // does stuff
}
call_my_function() {
  my_function(new \DateTime());
}
other_way_to_call_my_function() {
  $datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat(...);
  my_function($datetime);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to 'cheat' API to make it thing that "today is not today", but I can see now that I'm unable to do anything.