# How to force PHP/Apache to use another year?

Tags: php, apache

So, I was handed an old project by another employee. It's horribly coded and almost made me quit my job. Twice. Because I don't have that much time (I was given 2 weeks for this task), I can't rewrite the entire thing. I modified it as I was asked, and currently, I'm doing the testings. The problem is, the code should alter it's behavior in other years. The problem with this problem is, that there is no central location where the current year is set, it's all over the code using `date("Y")` which would force me to change around 200 files.

So, the easiest solution would be to tell PHP in the beginning: "Hey, it's year 20xx". I tried `date_default_timezone_set()`, but this didn't help me at all. So what I'm looking for is:

- A PHP-command which changes the current year to the set value (like`Set_Date("Y", 2016);`)
- An Apache-Servercommand which changes the current time (like`setdate -Y 2016`)

Is there any way or at least a workaround to make the script think it's another year?

Comment: You need to do that just for testing right?  Can't you temporarily change your OS time?

Comment: @Flosculus There are other developers and even running tools on this server, changing the time might influence their work or break something. Also, there are a few cronjobs running, so changing the entire system time is probably the last of all solutions.

Comment: Run on a different server.  Nothing else is going to work.

Comment: Hmm, I might have a solution...  Its a bit hacky though.  Do you have a list of all PHP functions in use that depend on the time?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use libfaketime (https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)?

Comment: No....because that changes the time for anything linked against the lib (i.e. php). Nor can you use a funky timezone (we used to do this for y2k testing) because you still need to modify all the code to test it. Spinning up a VM should take around 30 minutes (assuming you don't already have an image). Which looks like an awful lot less effort than any other solution.

Comment: @symcbean I'm not sure I understand. Can't you just use LD_PRELOAD to have it affect PHP (assuming that's available)? Something like this answer to a similar question suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25170140/548097 (Although, using a VM as you suggest is probably the best answer.)

Comment: You could compile a second PHP installation and modify the `date()` function to return a fake date.

Comment: @Hyrm: sww 'Y U NO WORK's comment above. Other developers are sharing the same PHP installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine functions using **runkit_function_redefine()**
But you need to setup the [runkit PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php)

**NOTE** : i didn't test it !

```
<?php 
print date("Y");

$date = 'print "Hello, it is a new definition of date function <" . $Y . ">"; return 2014; ';
runkit_function_redefine('date', '$Y', $date);

date("Y");
```

Comment: This should work - and combined with an auto-prepend and a browser side cookie needs no changes to the existing code and can't run in parallel with other work.

Comment: Jep, this did it without issues Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not suitable for your case but I thought I should share this abuse of namespaces:

```
<?php

namespace FakeTime;

function date($format, $time=null){
    return 2001;
}

var_dump(date('Y'));
```

Comment: That is beautifully horrible.  Unfortunately, judging from his desperation, he is using `php < 5.3`

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of other users suggestion and how to I use [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime). 
No need for a PECL extension.

You can very easily fake the time by modifying `/etc/apache2/envvars`
just add:

```
export FAKETIME="2015-12-04 12:41:15"
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1
```

Make sure `LD_PRELOAD` points to the git source. 
Now restart your apache2 and you'll be back in time right at the point where you'd asked this question!

Comment: This is basically Hrym's comment and DanFromGermany's answer, isn't it ;-)

Comment: Now that you said it, yes indeed it looks like that. It wasn't my intend to do so. I just posted what I use :/ Should I remove my post ?

Comment: I think that if you edit the answer and clarify you're explaining how to configure the library suggested in other question it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Frist compile libfaketime as suggested https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime

Dynamically load baked libfaketime into the scripts you need

```
if (!extension_loaded('libfaketime')) {
    dl('libfaketime.so');
}
```

Optional:

Use `auto_prepend_file` configuration to prepend the `dl(..` comand to every file.

Other possible way is to simply compile a second PHP installation and modify the date functions: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c