# Can I intercept a user-defined global function in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add customization to a Wordpress theme. Instead of replacing the original code, I'm using a "child theme" technique where I can replace files individually.

Now, that original code invokes the `get_footer()`, and I like to intercept that call so that I can insert my own html output before the actual get_footer function does its work.

I've read about the PHP 5's __call method but that only applies to classes whereas the WP code is not using classes but global functions. So I cannot use that technique, right?

Comment: If you have runkit (http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension installed on your machine you can redefine/rename existing functions.

Comment: yes, you can do it, see my previous response here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34089161/4098311

Answer (score 1):

`get_footer()` function just find and load proper template for the footer. There is a hook in WP `get_footer` that rans just before template being loaded.

Codex says that is not good to echo-es from this function, but you can use it to load your own template just before template that `get_footer()` loads.

You can do something like this in your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'get_footer', 'my_hook_fn' );
function my_hook_fn() {
   load_template('my_template_file.php');
}
```

[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_footer)

I use that thick in several sites, they do not use child themes, but I think this will do the trick.