# Offset server date/time for a specific subdirectory

Tags: php, linux, apache, redhat

I've got a web server running Red Hat Linux, Apache, and PHP. For that server (and apparently only for that server), there seems to be a problem with the way PHP date output is working on Sundays. I can spin up a Vagrant box on a local machine that has its date set to Sunday, run the exact same code, and everything works as expected. However, on my live web server, it seems to be working differently on Sundays and breaking a time-sensitive function. I'd like to run some tests before Sunday rolls around again, but changing the date for the entire server is not an option.

So.

Is there a way (perhaps using .htaccess or something similar) to offset the date PHP reports for a certain subdirectory?

Comment: `date` depends on server's time zone. This is why good guys who created PHP gave us `DateTime` class and `DateTimeZone` so you can select at any time the time zone and how to output the date string out. Your server runs its own time zone and most likely many services depend on it. Changing it to fit the need of a PHP script *probably* isn't the best way to go. That's why if I were you, I'd scrap that piece of PHP code with `date` function and re-implement it with `DateTime` class. That way you have complete control of everything related to dates.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the subdir and add something like: `php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"`. You can also set the timezone in a php file using [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set). Here is also the list of supported timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for use in either method.

Comment: Sure. And thanks for the feedback! The problem is, though, I need to jump ahead by a few days, not just a few hours. So simply changing the timezone won't get me there (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Then this is likely a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923848/change-todays-date-and-time-in-php

Comment: Also, stuff like the date function is relative to the timestamp passed in. If no timestamp is passed in, it uses the current time. You could also just set `$time=time()` and pass that into all calls to `date()` and if/when you want to change the date/time you can add/subtract from that timestamp.