# How to use Carbon::setTestNow() in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, time, php-carbon

For testing purposes I want to set the date to a specific date. I'm now trying to do that using the [Carbon lib](https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon), but it fails to do so:

```
Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1));
printf(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));  // prints 2018-06-28 13:21:06
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I globally set the time to a specific date?

Comment: There is already a question on how to set date and time globally in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923848/change-todays-date-and-time-in-php

Answer (score 7):

[date()](http://php.net/date) is a regular PHP function that doesn't have anything to do with Carbon and 
[Carbon::setTestNow()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing) does not change the system clock thus it's the expected behaviour.

I presume you just want to use Carbon all the way:

```
Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1));
echo Carbon::now();
```

Comment: I just found out the same. Unfortunately I can't use Carbon all the way because there are many calls to `time()` across the codebase. is there any way that i can change the time globally for all php code?

Comment: That means that your code is not really testable, sorry.

Comment: Also worth noting that `Carbon::setTestNow();` can be used to reset the time in Carbon to normal, so you don't affect later tests in your suite.