# Set system date in script?

Tags: php, date

Does PHP provide a way to set the system date within a script?

i.e. so that I can make `date('Y')` return `1999` even though it's currently `2021`.

I want to be able to quickly set the system date for debugging/testing purposes.

Perhaps "system date" is the wrong phrase. I only want it to be changed for the same script, whilst it's running.

Comment: You could always manually replace the call to `date('Y')` with any hardcoded string you want to do a test run.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the server date for a test creates a host of other problems. Don't do it!

You can always use a timestamp as a second parameter in your script. With strtotime() you can test the script with any date.

```
$ts = time();
$ts = strtotime('1999-01-01');  
echo date('Y', $ts);  //1999
```

After the test, the line is commented out with strtotime and the time stamp is then initialized with time(). The date ('Y') then behaves like without a second parameter.

```
$ts = time();
//$ts = strtotime('1999-01-01');  
echo date('Y', $ts);  //2021
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way using strictly PHP, however according to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923946/13219701) answer, you can use `shell_exec("date 09-09-99")` to run a shell command and set the time of the system like that.
I wouldn't recommend it though, since it could mess with something else.