# Change date within php-script

Tags: php, date

Happy Easter to all!

How can I manipulate the date within a php script (without relating it to a specific timestamp)?

For example:

```
echo date('Y'); // outputs 2021
setNewDateMagically(2019, 01, 01);
echo date('Y'); // outputs 2019
```

Is that possible?

There ist a question ([Change today's date and time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923848/change-todays-date-and-time-in-php)) about the same topic but it's more than 10 years old.
So I ask my question anyway, because there might be new solutions in the meantime.

Comment: Php gets the current time and date from the server. And maybe there is a way to customize this data, like there is a way to customize the timezone with date_default_timezone_set();

Comment: I think you can find an answer in this post: Set system date in script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533072/set-system-date-in-script/66534070#66534070

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change today's date and time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923848/change-todays-date-and-time-in-php)